# java.net.UnknownHostException InetAddress.getAllByName with many A-Records

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I am getting a UnkonwHostException if I try to resolve a DNS Name which return more that 20 A Records.

To reproduce this, create a DNS Record with 20 A-Records and try to get it via:

```
try {
 InetAddress[] var3 = InetAddress.getAllByName("manyrecords.and.longname.example.org");
}catch (Exception ex) {
 System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Reducing the DNS records to 5 for the subdomain, the query works again.
Tested with

openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17

openJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2, mixed mode)

On windows it seems to work.